# Java 16 Robot.mouseMove moving to wrong position

Tags: java, java-8, awt, awtrobot, java-16

I have an old project (using `java 8`) with the part of code I want to reuse in the project based on `java 16`:

```
Point p = new Point(x, y);
while (!MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().equals(p)) {
    robot.mouseMove(p.x, p.y);
}
```

And it not works properly with `java 16`, i.e. mouse isn't moving to the specified point (in `java 8` all is ok).

After several experiments, I think its because of Windows display scaling (125%), since I check screen size:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()
```

and in `java 8` this returns the correct `[width=1920,height=1080]`

but in `java 16` I get `[width=1536,height=864]` = [1920, 1080] / 1.25

I really can't understand how code can give different results just because of different JDKs

How can I fix it?

Comment: *"I really can't understand how code can give different results just because of different JDKs"* I'm not certain, but I'd guess far fewer people used display scaling back in the Java 8 days. (I don't know the solution to the problem.)

Comment: BTW - does a `MouseMotionListener` produce consistent numbers across Java versions 8 & 16?